# How apply api on pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

My data frame

```
uid,api_url
1, abc.com
2, xyz.com
```

my json api have key `url` has to taken from the `api_url` of the data frame and get the response

```
  jso ='''{
    "ui_id": "1111",
    "data": {
    "url": "xxxxxxx"
    }
    }'''
    json_d = json.loads(jso)
```

My code

```
def doc_(response):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.post("abc.com/v3/doc",headers=headers,json=json_d)
    return response.text
```

To create a new column in the data frame

`df['response'] = df['api_url'].apply(doc_)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update/regenerate your `json_d` for each `api_url` on each API request.
Also, apply better naming for functions/arguments.

```
def query_api(api_url):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    json_d = {'ui_id': '1111', 'data': {'url': api_url}}
    response = requests.post("http://example.net/v3/doc", 
                             headers=headers, json=json_d)
    return response.text


df['response'] = df['api_url'].apply(query_api)
```

Comment: if my  json api have so many arguments do i need to pass all  example ` {
    "ui_id": "1111",
    "data": {
    "url": "xxxxxxx",
    type": "in"}
    }`

Comment: @Nons, if all other keys are common, you could use `json_d` as mutable placeholder and update just `url ` key with `json_d['data']['url'] = api_url` on each function call

Comment: ok just one more if i need to add {'ui_id'} , which is uid from dataframe which datatype is int64, json_d = {'ui_id': uid, 'data': {'url': api_url}} i am getting error NameError: name 'uid' is not defined

Comment: @Nons, Instead of changing conditions on the fly - you should have prepared all the conditions and post them in your question beforehand